# Sprite kit - How to move a sprite?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have some code which adds sprites at random intervals but now i want every new sprite added to move across the screen. This is what i have :

```
-(void)createRat {

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(120, 298);// those coordinates are the bottom left corner

SKSpriteNode *rat = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rat"];
rat.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
rat.zPosition = 6;
[rat setScale:0.5f];
[self addChild:rat];

// we now want to call this method again repeatedly at a random interval :)

float randomNum = arc4random_uniform(3)+3;
[self performSelector:@selector(createRat) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomNum];

}
```

????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add action to every sprite to make them moving, e.g.

```
SKAction *moveNodeUp = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:100.0 duration:1.0];
[rocketNode runAction: moveNodeUp];
```

And I suggest you having a look at  the apple
's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH11-SW1